# Double free or corruption freeing queue in C

Tags: c, linux, queue, free

I have a queue (In Linux, C) that uses the following structs:

```
typedef struct Packet {
    char buffer[600];
    int32_t buf_length;
} Packet;

typedef struct Node {
    Packet *packet_p;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct Queue {
    Node *front;
    Node *rear;
    int size;
} Queue;
```

After that I have the typical functions to push, pop, read the number of elements... Everything works fine. But, sometimes (Very very few of them) I get the following error:

```
double free or corruption (out)
```

after some time of debugging and adding prints to see where it fails, I found that the clear queue function causes this.

This is my function:

```
void clearQueue(Queue *queue) {

    printf("CQ1\r\n");
    while (!isEmpty(queue)) {
        Node *temp = queue->front;
        if (queue->front == NULL) {
            printf("CQX1\r\n");
            queue->rear = NULL;
        } else {
            printf("CQ2\r\n");
            if (temp->packet_p != NULL) {
                free(temp->packet_p);
            }
            printf("CQ3\r\n");
            if (temp != NULL) {
                free(temp);
            }
            printf("CQ4\r\n");
            if (queue->size > 0) {
                queue->size--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get right before crashing:

```
CQ1
CQ2
CQ3
CQ4
CQ2
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted
```

I have 2 frees in the clear function because the enqueue function is created this way:

```
void enqueue(Queue *queue, const Packet *item) {
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    newNode->packet_p = (Packet *)malloc(sizeof(Packet));
    if (newNode->packet_p == NULL) {
        free(newNode);
        return;
    }

    memcpy(newNode->packet_p->buffer, item->buffer, item->buf_length);
    newNode->packet_p->buf_length = item->buf_length;

    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (isEmpty(queue)) {
        queue->front = newNode;
       queue->rear = newNode;
    } else {
        queue->rear->next = newNode;
        queue->rear = newNode;
    }
    queue->size++;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this? Can it be reworked in a better way ( Pretty sure it does, but I got no other ideas)

Comment: I don't see where `queue->front` gets changed. So the second time through the loop, you attempt to `free` the same `Node`.

Comment: If you [edit] and provide a [mcve], that is a piece of code that can be copy/pasted into an IDE and run without guesswork and without needing to stitch pieces of code together, more people will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your clearQueue function isn't updating the front pointer in your queue. The front pointer should be advanced to the next node before freeing the current one.

something like this:

```
void clearQueue(Queue *queue){
    Node *temp;
    while(queue->front != NULL){
        temp = queue->front;
        queue->front = queue->front->next; //Advance front to the next item
        if(temp->packet_p != NULL){
           free(temp->packet_p);
        }
        free(temp);
        if(queue->size > 0){
           queue->size--;
        }
    }
    queue->rear = NULL;
   
}
```

Comment: Dammit, thank you!. I am changing the code right now